# Git isn't traking some of my folders

Tags: git, grails

I did `git add .` in root directory, after that I did

```
git commit -m "abc"
```

itd...
after that, in my repo I did not find directories like /src /lib etc...

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is only tracking files. So if the folders `src/` and `lib/` are empty, then they won't be added to the repo.

If you want to track them anyway, what I usually do is adding an empty file called `.keep`. You can also use a `.gitignore` file for folders containing cache data or generated files you don't want to track but for which you want to keep the directory in the repo.

Also, the `git add` flag to add every change in you repo is `git add -A`. This will stage every change (deleted, added and changed files).